# Make 2 workspaces on 1 monitor in GNOME Shell?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, workspaces, fullscreen

Is there any way to make 2 workspaces on one screen with GNOME Shell 3.36 on Ubuntu 20.04? I need this because I want to use browser (or any other app) in full screen mode but only on half of my screen, but I've found no solutions. So maybe there is a way to place 2 workspaces on one screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have two workspaces displayed on a single screen, not in Gnome Shell and not in any other desktop environment I know.

An easy way to put your browser in half of the screen is to use the shortcut key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/right</kbd>. This will tile the browser window on the left or right of your screen. With similar hotkeys, other applications can then be made to occupy the other half.

A similar approach works for maximizing the window on the entire screen: use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or drag the window to the top edge.

With the mouse, you quickly achieve the same by dragging the window to the left or right edge of the screen. Once the cursor is close to the edge, a colored area will appear, indicating that you can now release the mouse button to have the window tiled.

Comment: Yes, I know about this, but it puts window in half of the screen in its usual mode, and I'm talking about any possibility to make the same with the window in fullscreen mode, like [here](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/brave/original/2X/1/12995d7091dc6d80b6fe292f1e87ec8710acf566.png)

Comment: Sorry, but I started my answer with answering your question: telling that it is not possible. It is a disappointing answer, but, unless I am proven wrong (which I would hope), may be the valid answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the GNOME-Extension ShellTile

[image]

The simplest way to use the extension is to first, enable it by clicking the [image] slider to set it one then holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, slide another window over the first (during which there will be a screen highlighting) after which release and the two windows will self position. The trick is to move windows to corners to achieve 4 in a single screen.

Here, I have created 4 different windows on one screen.

[image]

You can install GNOME Shell Extensions on 20.04 by following the steps [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop)

Comment: I've installed it, but still can't understand how to make two workspaces on one screen or how to resize a fullscreen window.

Comment: @Kalich I've amended my answer to show how to use the extension. If that works for you please be kind enough to accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: But on your screenshot the browser is in its usual mode, and I'm talking about any possibility to split the window in fullscreen mode, like [here](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/brave/original/2X/1/12995d7091dc6d80b6fe292f1e87ec8710acf566.png)

Comment: @Kalich then I'm confused by your question. One window is a browser the other is an app. Your screenshot seem to imply the same - only one bottom bar but 4 windows which is possible with Shell Tile. What am I missing here?

Comment: On my screenshot all windows are opened in fullscreen mode and then split to four windows, while on yours windows are not in fullscreen mode